# Non trivial vector bundle

Tags: differential-geometry

For every line $l$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ we write $l^\perp$ for the plane orthogonal to $l$. Let $F$ be :
$$F = \{(u,l) | l\in\mathbb{P}^2(\mathbb{R}),u\in l^\perp\}$$

How do you show that this is not isomorphic to the trivial bundle on $\mathbb{P}^2(\mathbb{R})$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume there were a non-vanishing section $g: P^2(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow F$. Precomposing with the quotient map $S^2 \rightarrow P^2(\mathbb{R})$, one gets for each $v \in S^2$ a $w \in \mathbb{R}^3$ - namely the vector appearing in g(v) -  which is nonzero and perpendicular to $v$. But this defines a nowhere vanishing vector field on $S^2$.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot, but that uses (I think) the hairy ball theorem which I don't know how to prove (without looking on the internet). I was looking for something a little bit more elementary. If nobody gives a more elementary answer I'll accept yours though because it does indeed answer the question.

Comment: This would also be a contradiction to the Poincare-Hopf theorem, maybe you know that one?